# How can I get the first item in a list using free marker?

Tags: html, freemarker

I have the following code which contains about 12 items but I only need to retrieve the first item. How can I display the first item in my list?

My code is:

```
<#list analysttest.rss.channel.item as item>
          <div>
                  <h3 class="bstitle">${item.title}</h3>
                  <span class="bsauthor">${item.author}</span> 
                  <span>${item.pubDate}</span>
                  <p>${item.description}</p>

          </div>
      </#list>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`analysttest.rss.channel.item[0]` gives the fist item, which you can `#assign` to a shorther name for convenience. Note that at least 1 item must exist, or else you get an error. (Or, you can do something like `<#assign item = analysttest.rss.channel.item[0]!someDefault>`, where `someDefault` is like `''`, `[]`, `{}`, etc, depending on what you need. There's even a shorter `<#assign item = analysttest.rss.channel.item[0]!>` form, which uses a multi-typed "generic nothing" value as the default... see in the Manual.)

Listing is also possible, though odd for only one item: `<#list analysttest.rss.channel.item[0..*1] as item>`, where `*1` means at most length of 1 (requires FreeMarker 2.3.21 or later). This works (and outputs nothing) even if you have 0 items.

Comment: Detailed explanation. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
<#assign item = analysttest.rss.channel.item[0]>

<div>
  <h3 class="bstitle">${item.title}</h3>
  <span class="bsauthor">${item.author}</span> 
  <span>${item.pubDate}</span>
  <p>${item.description}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked this as well. Good way to assign.