# Can I pass a List of String[] into Freemarker?

Tags: java, html, arrays, freemarker

The data model I am using for freemarker to process is

```
Map<String, Object> templateDataModel = new HashMap<>();
```

I have a list of String Arrays that I would like to pass into this map like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> listOfServers = new ArrayList<>();

for (Server server : object.getServers) {
    String[] ser = new String[2];
    //get the name
    ser[0] = server.getName();
    //get the port
    ser[1] = server.getPort();

    lostOfServers.add(ser);
}

templateDataModel.put(serverList, listOfServers);
```

The reason behind the arraylist is that the server has at least 2 data points that go with it (in this case name and port) and a String List or other collection can't hold what I need (correct if I'm wrong).

In my freeMarker template I would like to loop this list of servers and display various different values like this:

```
<#list serverList as server>
    <tr>
        <td>${server[0]}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>${server[1]}</th>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

I am getting this message in my output:

```
freemarker.template.DefaultObjectWrapper didn't convert java.util.ArrayList to a TemplateHashModel. 
Generally, you want to use a Map<String, Object> or a JavaBean as the root-map (aka. data-model) parameter. The Map key-s or JavaBean property names will be the variable names in the template.
```

It seems like I can't do this. Is this correct? If so any advice on data structure to use that is supported by freemarker?

I'm new to Java, and reading up on freemarker. Please excuse any basic things I don't understand, but I would really like to get this freemarker thing to work.

EDIT: **************************

Here I have decided using

```
Map<String, List<List<String>>>
```

instead of

```
Map<String, List<String[]>>
```

Template looks something like this now:

```
<#list serverEntries as serverEntry>
    <tr>
        <#list serverEntry as serverAttribute>
            <td>${serverAttribute}</th>
        </#list>
    </tr>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it appears that you have passed `listOfServers` (or some other `ArrayList`) to `Template.process` (or `Environment.process`), instead of `templateDataModel`.

Comment: I verified that I am passing the Map<String, Object> and StringWriter to the template.process method. thanks for the input

Comment: something I'm wondering is if there is an Array directive, or how to make one

Comment: @Alan: The error message says that you have passed in an `ArrayList`. Maybe you aren't looking at the right `Template.process` call. Check where the call was made from in the stack trace. I'm not sure what do you mean by an Array directive.

Comment: The goal for this is like in this post, where Jimmy is able to call item.author, item.pubDate etc. The approach I used to store the author, pubDate, description etc. is using an ArrayList passed into the Map. Perhaps this is the wrong approach. How might I accomplish that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468941/how-can-i-get-the-first-item-in-a-list-using-free-marker/35469280#35469280

Comment: I'll try xml as data model

Comment: Of course you can have `List`-s in the data-model. That's perfectly common. Again, the error message simply says that you aren't passing the `Map` in as the data-model "root", but the `ArrayList` itself.

Comment: thanks, I have switched to lists and now it is working

Comment: Changed what to lists? Both `List`-s and arrays should work.

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity, I have made an edit to the post. Please see the bottom of the first post. I was not able to get it to work using Map<String, List<String[]>> as dataModel.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. Arrays and lists should work the same in templates. Also, the quoted error message still talks about something entirely different.